# Is it possible to call NSIS script in java Swing Program

Tags: java, nsis

I have a java code in that i need to call NSIS script at run time, is it possible to call an NSIS script via java code at run time, if it possible kindly give an example..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Thanks Thomas, i don't have any idea about using NSIS script bcz i'm new to this platform, give a example for this..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to call Ant or NSIS script via Java Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440295/is-it-possible-to-call-ant-or-nsis-script-via-java-code)

Comment: "..kindly give an example.."  Kindly name your budget.  (To put that another way:  These forums are not a code generation machine.)

Comment: Hi Andrew Thompson,I ask if it possible or not, its possible means give the cmd for run time execution not a application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can "call" NSIS from java.

The only option I see is, since you have [command line options](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#) for NSIS, you can call the command line options from java using `Runtime.exec()`

```
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(your_NSIS_instructions);
```

Comment: I have tried this code but it shows error: install_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

  
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
    try {
     proc = rt.exec("outfile"+ "simple installer.exe"+ "installDir $DESKTOP"+
 
"section" +
 
"setOutPath $INSTDIR" +
 
"file setup.exe" +
 
"sectionEnd");
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
   }});

Comment: @Jack Sparrow _I have tried this code but it shows error_: What error?