# Running ant script from within scala program

Tags: scala, ant

I tried

> val cmd = sys.process.Process(Seq("C:\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin\ant", "everythingNoJunit"),   new java.io.File(scriptDir))
>
> cmd.lines

and got this error:

> CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

How do I run the ant script from within scala app?

Comment: Can you run ANY command? If you start with something simple, such as the examples in the documentation, you can then mutate it step by step into what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is that your should be using "ant.bat" instead of "ant" on a windows machine as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18395992/1259917)

In addition to that, I would suggest using a non-windows styled path so you don't have to escape the backslashes:

```
val cmd = sys.process.Process(Seq("/apache-ant-1.9.3/bin/ant.bat", "everythingNoJunit"), new java.io.File(scriptDir))
```

Using this approach, I'm able to run an an ant target successfully when my scala application is also in "c:".

Comment: Thanks also for the tip on backslashes!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I had fun starting a web server from within a Scala application in Eclipse and seeing the messages in the console ( I used `cmd.run` instead ).