# How to set logger when running Ant from Java?

Tags: java, logging, ant

I can run Ant from Java as it said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6733831/258483

It works.

But it works silently. How to set logging so that it logs exact the same it logs during normal command line run?

Comment: Do you mean this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6440342/738746? It seems to show how to add a logger listener that prints to the standard out/err streams.

Comment: Can I add standard `SLF4J` logging?

Comment: Looks like there's no implementaiton for SLF4J - http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/BuildListener.html. There is one for commons and log4j.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to log4j-over-slf4j ?

Comment: @Suzan Cioc Try Log4Ant => http://jwaresoftware.org/wiki/log4ant/home which claims to be "a full bridge to the SLF4J library"