# JSP engines without webserver

Tags: java, jsp, webserver

Within the scope of implementing my own webserver in Java I want to support JSPs. For the moment I don't want to write a JSP engine myself but use an existing one.
I found several JSP engines (e.g. `Jasper` or `Jakarta`) but they all come within their own webservers.
Is there a JSP engine implementation that is available as a standalone library?

Comment: Why? JSP is only defined to run inside a Servlet container. You've got a large task in front of you if you're reimplementing Tomcat, or Glassfish, or JBoss.

Comment: thats why I am searching for a standalone library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be a very difficult task. You will lose the benefit of runtime compilation, hot deploy, mapping, jsp precompilation / caching and probably much more.

Outlooking these facts, you can always compile your JSPs with some of the tools that are already provided by the app server.

Here is a short sample :

- Apache Jasper, you can download from maven the standalone api from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/jasper) and have a look at the javadoc [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html).
- Weblogic jspc : [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/reference.html#wp57794)
- You own parser ???

Ant has bundled a bunch of optional tasks that you could call to [pre]compile your jsps :

- [Weblogic Compilation task](http://antinstaller.sourceforge.net/manual/manual/OptionalTasks/wljspc.html)
- [Japser Compilation task](http://antinstaller.sourceforge.net/manual/manual/OptionalTasks/jspc.html)

Then call ant from your server logic ([Is it possible to call Ant or NSIS scripts from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440295/is-it-possible-to-call-ant-or-nsis-scripts-from-java-code#6440342)) or precompile your JSPs when you build your server.

Also, if it's all about creating a web container then why not just write plain and simple [servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can take [jastow](https://github.com/undertow-io/jastow), which is fork of jasper (from tomcat) to be easier fitted into clean servlet implementation.

It was done to add support for JSP to undertow servlet implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [GNUJSP](http://www.klomp.org/gnujsp/) , but the project is not active i guess.

Answer (score 0):

In some projects JSPs are precompiled, so there are ant and maven builds integrating a JSP compiler.

- Maven: [JspC](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jspc/)

I would work on the basis of that, as it is in active use. Inspect the generated java or jvm byte code (javap) to provide (too) specific implementation classes.