# Use log4j while executing Ant script through java code

Tags: java, ant, log4j

I have seen few examples where ANT is run though java code. [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440295/is-it-possible-to-call-ant-or-nsis-scripts-from-java-code/6440342#6440342) is one such example. Here DefaultLogger is being used:

```
Project p = new Project();
.
.
DefaultLogger consoleLogger = new DefaultLogger();
consoleLogger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
consoleLogger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
consoleLogger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
p.addBuildListener(consoleLogger);
```

However I want to use log4j. I have mylog4j.xml already defined in the application. I want to use same XML for configuring **ANT LOGGER ("org.apache.tools.ant")** and want to use this logger. Can someone tell me how to do so in java code?

**Note**: I have done something like:

```
org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener log4j = new Log4jListener();  
p.addBuildListener(log4j);
```

But I don't know how to specify the log4j config xml file path to ant launcher.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the location of your file using the ANT's API. However, you can use the class [**`org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator`**](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html). e.g.:

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("/path/to/mylog4j.xml");
Project p = new Project(); 
p.addBuildListener(new Log4jListener());
```

See also [*Listeners & Loggers*](https://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html) in the [*Apache Ant 1.9.4 Manual*](http://ant.apache.org/manual/).